# Get the list of function for a process

Tags: c++

I have a c++ application which does a lot of different tasks.
The application is big and I am having trouble in finding the code for a particular task.Is there a way that I can get the list of all the function in my project ( source code ) when I execute a particular task,which can be started by the shell like normal process.I don't want to go step by step in gdb as it takes a lot of time .

Comment: you may write a script through which you will get the names of all functions in your project.

Comment: what kind of script ,any direction for that

Comment: What I did once was wrote a python script to search for all the functions in the c++ program using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

doxygen can do this job for you by using `CALL_GRAPH` and `CALLER_GRAPH` settings: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_caller_graph

But remember that it's difficult task for C++ as it cannot follow the virtual calls, abstract classes and things like that. So it only guess from direct function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling your application using Valgrind can allow you to generate a complete runtime call graph. See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html

A powerful tool called [KCacheGrind](https://kcachegrind.github.io/) is used to visualize the generated data. A Windows equivalent is [WinCacheGrind](http://ceefour.github.io/wincachegrind/).

As it is performed at runtime, you can focus on the specific process you want to profile, while static solutions will create graph calls that are probably too large to be useful.